# How do I change the display size of a map from a shapefile with matplotlib?

Tags: python, geopandas, pandas, matplotlib

I'm completely new to shapefiles. I was able to use GeoPandas to plot some data over a map of the US I got from census.gov. I'm having getting the map to be at a viewable size. I adjusted the figsize parameter multiple times, but it doesn't seem to increase the size enough. From what I've read so far, shapefiles shouldn't be modified. How can I make the subplot larger?

```
map_df = gdp.read_file(shape_file)
map_df.head()
map_df.plot()

covid_max_cap_df = hospital_data.groupby(['statename']).InBedsOccCOVID__Numbeds_Est.max()
covid_max_cap_df.drop('United States')

merged_map = map_df.set_index('NAME').join(covid_max_cap_df)
merged_map.rename(columns={'InBedsOccCOVID__Numbeds_Est':'covid_occ_rate'}, inplace=True)

var = 'covid_occ_rate'
vmin, vmax = covid_max_cap_df.min()-10, covid_max_cap_df.max()+10

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,figsize=(30,30))
merged_map.plot(column=var, cmap='Reds', linewidth=0.8, ax=ax, edgecolor='0.8')
ax.axis('off')
ax.set_title('COVID-19 Peak Hospital Occupancy Rate', fontdict={'fontsize':25, 'fontweight':3})
ax.annotate('Source: CDC, June 2020',xy=(0.1, .08),  xycoords='figure fraction', 
            horizontalalignment='left', verticalalignment='top', 
            fontsize=12, color='#555555')

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='Reds', 
                              norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax))
sm._A = []
cbar = fig.colorbar(sm)
```

[image]

Comment: You have some island geometry on the right side of the plot which causes the whole map to scale down.

Comment: Can you set the axis limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [in geopandas documentation](https://geopandas.org/mapping.html), you can use `mpl_toolkits` in order to fit and align the plot axes and the legend axes:

```
 from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
 divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
 cax = divider.append_axes("right", size="5%", pad=0.1)
 adm_gdf.plot(column='pop_est', ax=ax, legend=True, cax=cax)
```

[image: fit-plot-with-colorbar]

There are other interesting alternatives [in this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195758/set-matplotlib-colorbar-size-to-match-graph).

Comment: In your example, how do you increase the whole figure size vertically? Say, make it twice as tall - the whole image.

Comment: I recommend posting another question with your problem. But you can see that the image adapts/fits to the bounds by default. If you want to change the fig size, [check the docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html).